# Backpack Laravel not updating configuration

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've modified some settings such as:

```
project_name' =>
```

and

```
 'project_logo'   =>
```

on laravelproject\vendor\backpack\crud\src\config\backpack\base.php but the logo and the title has not been updated on the page.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Follow the instructions on Backpack documentation. Don't edit any file inside `vendor` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a general rule of thumb on Laravel, like @ElektaKode  said in his comment:

**do not edit any file inside vendor folder**

go to:

```
 config\backpack\base.php
```

there is where you can modify `project_name,project_logo`

and do not forget to clear the config cache after editing.